# Errors when installing rtcheck

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install "rtcheck". I do `sudo apt-get install rtcheck`, but during the installation an error occurs.

```
  andrea@andrea-K53SD:/$ sudo apt-get install rtcheck
     [sudo] password for andrea: 

Reading package lists... Done 

 Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package rtcheck
     andrea@andrea-K53SD:/$
```

**What does this mean?**

Comment: have you done sudo apt-get update before installing ?

Comment: I can not find reference to rtcheck in either the Ubuntu Software Centre or on the internet. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: as I understood, rtcheck is use to run other programm in the realtime way. A friend of mine told me to use it to run a programm he gave me. but he didn't told me how, and now i can't reach him.

Comment: OK I have found the package http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/mrg/slc5X/x86_64/RPMS/repoview/rtcheck.html I'll try and install it and get back to you.

Comment: as far as I know I dont see any programs for Ubuntu but wait and see. may be top people can eye this and hope that they may answer. all the best.

Comment: @SimplySimon all the best my friend. That package is old and existed in RPM so you need alien software to convert into deb and we need think for dep also because its old. all the best my friend. let us know what you got.

Comment: I have checked the file, and extracted it. The programme is already compiled and can be found in the `~/Downloads/rtcheck-0.7.6-1.el5rt.x86_64/etc/rc.d/init.d` folder. I imagine that it would be possible to copy the `rc.d/init.d` to the /etc` root folder on your hdd.

Comment: I tried to do it but it still doesn't work.  I can't fix the "Unable to locate package rtcheck" problem.

Comment: You will be unable to use apt-get to install rtcheck as it doesn't exist in the software repositories. SimplySimon is offering you a possible way of running it. Considering it's age and the probable dependencies it's not likely to function. What program did your friend indicate that you would need rtcheck to run?